# Do class properties get overwritten on extended classes?

Tags: php, class, oop, properties

Say for example I have two classes `A` and `B`:

A:

```
class A {
    private $name = "Joe";
}
```

B:

```
class B extends A {
       private $name = "Scotto";
}
```

What will the value of `$name` be? Does it overwrite the parent class property or will it be it's on instance if instantiated? Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: @naththedeveloper I could easily try it but I'm looking for a more in depth answer than just "Wow, okay that's what it does"

Comment: Why would it be replaced? Private means that only this class can access this property. Thus, each class has its own definition of `$name`. [Clicky](https://eval.in/private/830e62ffefe9ab)

Comment: However, when `$name` is defined as `protected` or `public`, it does get replaced by `Scotto`. I recommend reading [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) on visibility. It states in the example code, `We can redeclare the public and protected properties, but not private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest specifically reading [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#87413) on the documentation pages. The focus is on methods, but it's the same for properties

> ... private methods are visible only for the class that defines them and the child class does not see the parent's private methods. If the child doesn't see the parent's private methods, the child can't override them.

Your example:

```
class A {
  private $name = "Joe";

  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  private $name = "Scotto";
}

class C extends A {
  private $name = "Scotto";

  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;
$c = new C;

$a->getName(); // 'Joe'
$b->getName(); // 'Joe'
$c->getName(); // 'Scotto'
```